# Number of params in query params

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2

In the console output of the rails app I see something like this:

```
INFO: Started GET "/pharmacy?chart=medications&brand_name=BrandName_449&dose=6&form=Form_3&filter=phy_group"
    Processing by PharmacyController#level_one as JSON
      Parameters: {"chart"=>"medications", "brand_name"=>"BrandName_449", "dose"=>"6", "form"=>"Form_3", "filter"=>"phy_group"}
    Completed 200 OK in 73ms (Views: 0.4ms)
```

but if I say `puts params.length` it returns me **seven**.

What is happening? shouldn't it be **five**?

Comment: Optional params with defaults getting silenced?

Comment: what? I don't understand what you meant.

Comment: Try to define a route with an optional param, with a default value, e.g. Format defaulting to HTML. To see if that gets hidden in addition to the two mentioned by Christian.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

params implicitly contain `:controller` and `:action`, which are omitted in the output

Comment: so as a rule of thumb can I say in my code that ok params.length PLUS TWO?  for those two?

Comment: In your code, those two will show up. Just try Rails.logger.info "params: #{params}"